# Append Data to the Last Row of another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, match, paste

I simply need to grab a column (range) from one sheet, and append to another sheet. For some reason I keep getting an error 1004 - object/application defined error when trying to run the paste values function.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Sub copycontactsiratotpsd()

    Dim LastRowIRA2 As Long
    Dim LastRowIRA As Long
    Dim LastRowPOV As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long




    'activate source sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("IRA").Activate

    'copy from rev to ira AG to match # of rows for TPRM Contacts before appending
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Rev").Range("B2:B15000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IRA").Range("AG2:AG15000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'define last rows for all three instances
    LastRowIRA = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    LastRowIRA2 = ActiveSheet.Range("AG1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    lastrow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("TPD").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    LastRowPOV = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TPD").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count

    'if the number of lastrow in source sheet is equal to total VISIBLE last row within reference sheet then
        If LastRowIRA = LastRowIRA2 Then

            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("IRA").Activate

            'copy the data needed, values are generally less than 10000 rows
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10000").Copy

            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TPD").Range("A", lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'LINE WITH ERROR ABOVE




        'else display msg for error handling
        Else: MsgBox "Row Count is off! *CHECK*"

        End If


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("IRA").Activate
    Columns(33).EntireColumn.Delete

    End Sub
```

Comment: bad syntax:  range("A2") versus cells(row,column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow an answer to close this out:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10000").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TPD").Cells(lastrow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Or:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10000").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TPD").Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Such a simple change! For future knowledge gain, is there any benefit to using one over the other?

Comment: @VBAWARD in some cases certain actions will only acknowledge Range(), though it is easier to loop through Cells(r,c) when you want to iterate nested loops (otherwise you deal with "A" = 1, when you can just say for c = 1 to 20).  I personally tend to use Cells(,) unless i'm required to use Range().